# Testing wrapper around paho.mqtt.client with pytest. Callback is never executed

Tags: python, pytest, mqtt

I wrote a wrapper around the paho.mqtt.client class. Now I am writing tests using pytest to ensure it works.

```
def test_send_receive():

    def callback(client, userdata, message: paho.mqtt.client.MQTTMessage):
        assert str(message.payload.decode()) == "testmessage"

    def publishing(client: MqttHandler):
        client.pub_to_topic("testmessage", "test")
        time.sleep(3)

mqtt1 = MqttHandler("localhost")
mqtt2 = MqttHandler("localhost")
mqtt1.sub_with_callback("test", callback)

x = threading.Thread(target=publishing, args=(mqtt2,))
x.start()
x.join()
```

This testcode works fine when I call it as a normal script. However when I execute the code in the pytest-environment the code within callback is never executed. Even if I raise an error instead of the assert statement the test passes. I am either looking for an answer on why the callback is never called in pytest-environment or a different solution for testing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be

```
mqttt1.sub_with_callback("test", test_send_receive.callback)
```

Since the `callback` function is declared as part of `test_send_receive`

Comment: When I add the callback with test_send_receive.callback it raises an Attribute error saying, that test_send_receive has no attribute "callback"